# Change UIImage Picker Button Label Text

Tags: ios, swift

The default text on the button for a user to confirm a picture when using the `.Camera` option for the `UIImagePicker` is "Use Picture".

Is there any way to change this to some other string?

Comment: `UIButton.setTitle("something")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
func chooseAlert(){


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Upload Image", message: "Choose Source For Image.", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
//                self.performSelector(#selector(self.useCamera), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)
                self.useCamera()
            }
        })

        let cameraRollAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Use Photo", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                self.useCameraRoll()
            }
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel){
            (action) in
            print(action)
        }

        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(cameraRollAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
```

In the IBAction of the Button call this function which will bring an alert on the screen. In the alert actions, change the title as per your wish. useCamera() and useCameraRoll() are user defined functions.